# Return exec output from program via parameter reference

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying to execute a shell command from within a C program.

For that I have built a wrapper function that will return the exit code of the command itself and use a parameter reference variable to give back the actual output of the program.

The exec function wrapper looks like this:

```
int _exec(const void *command, char **result) {
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];
    char *eof;

    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    while((eof = fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp)) != NULL);

    /* Fill the parameter reference */
    *result = strdup(path);

    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The calling part looks like this:

```
int result = 0;
char *tmp;

result =_exec("ls /", &tmp);
printf("%s", tmp);
```

Unfortunately in the calling part, when I `printf` `tmp`, it only contains the last line of the command output.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? How can I get all lines int `*result` and therefore into `tmp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fread` instead of `fgets`. `fgets` stops reading with each newline character, but you are saving all lines in the first positions of your `path` buffer. Also, you would need to keep track of the number of bytes already present at `path`, and save the data into the first unused position in `path` each time you call the reading function.

Comment: When I try `fread` it does not work at all: `fread(*result, 1, sizeof(char*), fp);`

Comment: Read the `fread` documentation to know what to pass as parameters. The first one will be `path`, as before. In `count` pass the size of your buffer, `sizeof(path)`; it will not read past the end-of-line. Actually you won't need the `while` loop as if it doesn't read all data, your buffer will be full anyways.

Comment: How would I know which array size I have to declare to path before reading?

Comment: You don't. Set a size that you expect will be able to hold all output text of the program. Else you would have to deal with dynamic memory, allocating it each time you see you'll be needing more.

Comment: You could also leave the closing of the file descriptor for later, and use ´fprintf´ instead of ´printf´ at the calling part of your program so that it directly prints the outputs of the executed command (with the file descriptor as parameter). The file descriptor could be closed later.